# Defining fields in Query Using Form in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a query that contains all my products and various attributes and descriptions.

However in my company we use several pricelists.

So I want to make a report to print the pricelists in a nice way. 
I want the query that the report is based on to be able to use get the column of the price to use from a Form.

The structure is the attributes in a table and another table containing the prices each with a header "Retail" / "Wholesale".

In the report the field is linked using a name "Price".

How can I define using the form if the field "Price" get the "Retail" or "Wholesale" values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use parameters in your query. I prefer to change the querydef based on what's in the form, but parameters is any easier way to go.

Start off with your Form that has the Retail or Wholesale...let's call it [Price-Type]. Let's say the form is called [Price Report]. That's all you need there.

Now create your query. In the design tab (I'm in Access 2007, not sure if it's in the same place in 2010), you want to click on "Parameters". It'll be in a "Show/Hide" group.

In the box that pops up, you'll enter [Forms]![Price Report]![Price-Type] and Data Type of Text.

Click OK.

In the query grid, add a column where you're going to enter a "calculated price". It'll be something like this:

`CalcPrice: Iif([Forms]![Price Report]![Price-Type]="Retail", [RetailPrice], [WholesalesPrice])`

Then you use that query and CalcPrice in your report. Of course, your IIF statement can go deeper depending on how many prices you have.